# shell script for replacing some files with symlinks

Tags: svn, ftp, shell

Some servers only support ftp to upload files.

When I export the a project from my subversion repository to my windows machine, all (linux) symlinks are replaces by placeholder-files:

```
link ../www_public/images
```

after uploading the all exported files I now use

```
find | xargs grep -P ^link
```

to find all those placeholders. I then replace them with the actual symlink manually.

**I would really like to automate this step with a shell-script.

How would I do this?**

Note:
If there is a better / different solution to this problem, don't hesitate to share it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
:
grep -lr '^link' . | while read placeholderfile
do
  linkfile=`cut -c6- "$placeholderfile"`
  ln -sf "$linkfile" "$placeholderfile"
done
```

**edit:** changed code above w.r.t. the comments below.

Comment: It's probably better to use cut -c6- (paths might have spaces). Also, I don't understand your ln statement. I'd expect something like ln -s "`pwd`/$linkfile" "$placeholderfile". (And possible remove the rm and use ln -sf.) It might also be that this is because I interpreted the question differently.

Comment: I didn't know for certain that the placeholder file had the same name as the link file.  Probably true, but I didn't assume.

Comment: Yes, the name of the placeholder file is the name of the symlink which is the same as the target name.